# Is there a more efficient way to manage large data than using facts?

Tags: prolog

I finished working on an AI project that manages long strings (About 1300 characters each),
the issue is the **Out of local stack** exception when trying to run the algorithm with a larger population **(NP)** than 10 or when trying a higher amount of iterations **(G)** than 20.
Currently, i manage data using facts like this:

`x(INDEX, NAMESTRING1, STRING1, NAMESTRING2, STRING2, FITNESS, VAR)`

for storing current solutions

and

`h(INDEX, NAMESTRING1, STRING1, NAMESTRING2, STRING2, FITNESS, VAR)`

for storing possible solutions made by the algorithm.

Where STRING1 and STRING2 are two lists containing the characters of two DNA chains. These lists get modified adding '_' by the algorithm.

My code calls to **assert/1** and **retract/1** about NP * G * 4 * 2 times during each iteration.

I tried:

1.- Setting a higher stack limit, which seems to work with reservation.

2.- Using `!` where necessary.

I was wondering if managing data with a list of lists would solve the problem.

Comment: Asserting and retracting facts _should_ be very efficient and behave in the same way as inserting and removing document to/from an in-memory [Key-Value database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key%E2%80%93value_database). "Out of local stack space" indicates that your program recurses too deeply or has too many local variables in certain stack frames. Using "!" certainly helps as the Prolog Processor can optimize away stack frames "that will never be visited in the future". Depending on the algorithm you may have the possibility to repl. depth-first search with an iterative deepening approach?

Comment: It seems that the one clause that calcules the fitness of each new solution recurses too deeply and causes the Out of local stack exception. I'll post another question regarding how to improve it. Thanks.

**EDIT**
How do i select your answer as the solution? I am new to StackOverflow.

Comment: I will post it as an answer, then you can select it it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asserting and retracting facts *should* be very efficient and behave in the same way as inserting and removing document to/from an in-memory [Key-Value database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key%E2%80%93value_database).

"Out of local stack space" indicates that your program recurses too deeply or has too many local variables in certain stack frames. Using `!` certainly helps as the Prolog Processor can optimize away stack frames "that will never be re-visited in the future".

There is not enough information to judge this buit depending on the algorithm you may have the possibility to replace depth-first search with an iterative deepening approach (as one possibility that comes to mind)?